# Azure Function: how to received data via chunked encoding

Tags: azure-functions

All the function examples that Azure provides (for all the different supported languages) all seems to expect the input via regular ways of invoking the function via parameter=value whether its with POST or GET.

But in this case the data into the function comes in via external clients via HTTP chunked encoding (in an HTTP POST).  I cant see how to implement this as how to receive the chunked data in my function?

Comment: still seems to be http trigger, isn't it'?

Comment: yes still regulat HTTP, even is a POST, just has that different type of TRANSFER-ENCODING of "chunked"

Comment: What does your chunked response look like ? Any example ?

Answer (score 5):

Well it turns out that if you use chunked encoding on a POST request into an Azure function then the get_body() call will read the length value in the chunk and strip everything out, returning only the encapsulated data.  Problem solved!

Edit to add: while this works for the live production azure functions, it doesnt work for local development running functions on your local machine with VSCode